# How to pass props to react component through routing using react-router?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-redux

I want to pass some props to component on IndexRoute. Below is my code snippet:

```
render(root: Element) {
    const { store, params } = this as any;
    ReactDOM.render(
          <Provider {...{ store }} >
              <Router history={browserHistory}>
                  <Route path={window.location.pathname} component={App}>
                    <IndexRoute component={Step1} />
                    <Route path="step1" component={() => (<Step1 params={params} />)} />
                    <Route path="step1" component={() => (<Step2 params={params} />)} />
                  </Route>
            </Router>
          </Provider>
   , root);

}

//App Component
import * as React from 'react';


export var App: any = ({children}) => (

    <div>
        <div>{children}</div>
    </div>
)
```

On initial load I am able to load step1 as children but I want to pass some props from routing section to component.

How can I get this?

Please guide me.

Thanks,
Vijay

Answer (score 0):

Clone the elemnt using `cloneWithProps()`

```
var newStep1 = cloneWithProps(Step1, {prop1: 'value', prop2: 'value'});// add props
```

And pass it to `<IndexRoute />`

```
<IndexRoute component={newStep1} />
```

This should work..

[Reference](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/clone-with-props.html)

Answer (score 0):

In your App instead of `children` add this line:

```
{React.cloneElement(children, {params: params})}
```

That should work.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply add them through the `Route` object like this:

```
<Route path="step1" someParams={params} component={Step1} />
```

And then in the `Step1` component you can get them through the `props` again:

```
render() {
    console.log(this.props.route.someParams);
}
```