# Pass value to parent component using React Router v3

Tags: reactjs

I think the question was answered here, but I'm just not getting it.

[How to pass props to react component through routing using react-router?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39797657/how-to-pass-props-to-react-component-through-routing-using-react-router)

I want the user to search, and pass that value to the parent component so I can use it as state throughout the app.

```
// App.js
const App = ({ children }) => (
  <div>
    <Grid>
      { children }
    </Grid>
  </div>
);
```

Here's the routes. I want to update the state in App.js when Index.js searches (submits the form).

```
render(
  <Router history={ browserHistory }>
    <Route path="/" component={ App }>
      <IndexRoute name="index" component={ Index } />
```

Answer (score 0):

Well I don't know what you're Index component is doing but generally you pass a `setState` function into the child component which then calls it, which in turns triggers the parent. I.e.

```
//App.js

class App extends Component
{
  return_data = (data) => {
    this.setState(data);
  }

  render()
  {
    <div>
      <Index return_data={this.return_data}
    </div>
  }

}

// Index.js
class Index extends Component
{
  return_data = () => {
    let data = { input: this.input.value }
    this.props.return_data(data);
  }

  render()
  {
     <div>
       <input onChange={this.return_data) ref={(i) => this.input = i} />
     </div>
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to put state in `<App>`, then it needs to be a full React component -- not a functional one.  Assuming you make that conversion and create a callback function which updates that state value, then you might be wondering how to pass that callback down to whatever child page is being loaded by react-router.  For that, you want to use [React.cloneElement()](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-api.html#cloneelement) and do something like:

```
class App extends Component {
  ...

  state = { searchVal : ''}

  updateSearch(event){this.setState({searchVal : event.target.value})}

  ...

  render(){
    return (
      <div>
        <Grid>
          { React.cloneElement(this.props.children, {
              searchVal : this.state.searchVal,
              updateSearch : this.updateSearch 
          }) }
        </Grid>
      </div>
    )
  }

);
```